# jquery attr(src) not working first time

Tags: jquery, src, attr

I have a problem with changing src attributes in jquery.

This is some thumb:

```
<a href='Imagini/someimage.jpg' class='popup' data-id='n' >
   <img src='Imagini-min/someimage.jpg' />
</a>
```

Here, the container of the pop-up images:

```
<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <p id="close"><img src="Resurse/close.png" /></p>
    <p id="prev"><img src="Resurse/left.png" /></p>
        <img id="change" src="" data-id=""/>
    <p id="next"><img src="Resurse/right.png" /></p>
</div>
```

And jquery code:

```
$(".popup").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var img = $(this).attr("href");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $(".gallery").show();
    if(id != $(".gallery").find("#change").attr("data-id")){
        $(".gallery").find("#change").attr("src", img).hide().fadeIn(100);
        $(".gallery").find("#change").attr("data-id", id);

        SetPosition();
    }
   });

function SetPosition(){
    var width = $(".gallery").find("#change").width();
    var height = $(".gallery").find("#change").height();
    var button_h = $(".gallery #prev img").height();

    $(".gallery #prev").css("top",(height/2 - button_h + 10 ));
    $(".gallery #next").css("top",(height/2 - button_h + 8 ));

    $(".gallery").css("width",(width+50));
    $(".gallery").css("height",(height+10));
}
```

The problem is that when I open the browser and click any image I get:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2mq5gmg.jpg

If press once, going normal:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/qpqdk8.jpg

Someone had a problem like that?

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document ready event handler?

Comment: What do you mean by "open the browser and click any image" and "If press once, going normal" ???

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with your code and post the link in your question.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read the dimensions of the image before the browser has finished downloading it …

Comment: http://sitefortest.url.ph/articole.php?art=53 Try several times to open picture, you will understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

[change src](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/t96c30gc/3/)

HTML

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' src='Imagini/someimage.jpg' class='imagePopup' data-id='n' >
   <img src='Imagini-min/someimage.jpg' />
</a>
<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <p id="close"><img src="Resurse/close.png" /></p>
    <p id="prev"><img src="Resurse/left.png" /></p>
        <img id="change" src="" data-id=""/>
    <p id="next"><img src="Resurse/right.png" /></p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("a.imagePopup").click(function(e){
    //The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening. but it does not work in all browser.

    e.preventDefault();

    var img = $(this).attr("src");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var galleryID=$(".gallery").find("#change").attr("data-id");
    var targetImg=$(".gallery").find("#change");
    $(".gallery").show();    
    if(id != targetImg.attr("data-id")){
        targetImg.attr("src", img).hide().fadeIn(100).attr("data-id", id);
        alert("src="+targetImg.attr("src")+", id="+targetImg.attr("data-id"));

        SetPosition();
    }
   });

function SetPosition(){
    var width = $(".gallery").find("#change").width();
    var height = $(".gallery").find("#change").height();
    var button_h = $(".gallery #prev img").height();

    $(".gallery #prev").css("top",(height/2 - button_h + 10 ));
    $(".gallery #next").css("top",(height/2 - button_h + 8 ));

    $(".gallery").css("width",(width+50));
    $(".gallery").css("height",(height+10));
}
```

> Update

Call "SetPosition" function in img.load();
[Update](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/t96c30gc/5/)

Comment: Same probleme, check the images from: http://sitefortest.url.ph/articole.php?art=53 to see the error. I think that the jquery working slowly.

Comment: Thank you very much, is charging much more quickly in this way! Edit your post or I will give you correct answer now?

Comment: Tell yourself solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this change helps:

```
$(".gallery").find("#change").hide();
$(".gallery").find("#change").attr("src", img);
$(".gallery").find("#change").fadeIn(100);
```